# Agrupar una lista de objetos dentro de otra lista

Tags: java

Tengo una Lista de objetos y, dentro de mi lista, tengo otro objeto con listas. Quisiera saber la manera de poder agrupar esa lista de objetos dentro de la otra lista.

Tengo mi clase principal que es una lista

```
public class ListaA { 

    public ListaA(String nombre, String apelliddoP, String apellidoM, List<ListaB> listaB) {
        super();
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apelliddoP = apelliddoP;
        this.apellidoM = apellidoM;
        this.listaB = listaB;
    }

}
```

Esta clase a su vez tiene otra lista:

```
public class ListaB {

    private String telefono;

    public ListaB(String telefono) {
        super();
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ListaB [telefono=" + telefono + "]";
    }

}
```

¿Cómo puedo introducir valores como los siguientes

```
ListaTodos [nombre=a, apelliddoP=a, apellidoM=a, telefono=1]
ListaTodos [nombre=b, apelliddoP=b, apellidoM=b, telefono=2]
ListaTodos [nombre=c, apelliddoP=c, apellidoM=c, telefono=3]
ListaTodos [nombre=a, apelliddoP=a, apellidoM=a, telefono=2]
```

y que me pueda agrupar los valores por lista? Por ejemplo los que son nombre = a

```
ListaA [nombre=a, apelliddoP=a, apellidoM=a, listaB=[ListaB [telefono=1], ListaB [telefono=1], ListaB [telefono=2]]]

ListaA [nombre=b, apelliddoP=b, apellidoM=b, listaB=[ListaB [telefono=2]]]

ListaA [nombre=c, apelliddoP=c, apellidoM=c, listaB=[ ListaB [telefono=2]]]
```

Estoy intentando recorrerlo pero no me da.

```
    Map<String,List<ListaA>> agrupado = listaA.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ListaA::getNombre));
    System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    for (Map<String,List<ListaA>> lista: agrupado) {
        System.out.println(lista.toString());
    }
```

Me sale el error:

> Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

Answer (score 1):

Hola puedes usar el stream de la interfaz List en este caso puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
List<ListaA> listaTodos = new ArrayaList<ListaA>();
Map<String,List<ListaA>> agrupado = listaTodos.stream().collect(Collectors.groupBy(ListaA::getNombre));
 agrupado.forEach((nombre,lista)->{System.out.println("Nombre:" +  nombre + ": " + lista)})
```

Para esto en tus clases debes de implementar los set y get de cada atributo, esto te regresará un Map donde el String  que es el **nombre**, que es la clave de agrupación y la lista, es la lista de los elementos que cumplen con la condición de agrupación.

Comment: Gracias. estoy intendando recorrerlo pero no me da.

Comment: no pues iterar de esa forma el mapa, actualicé mi respuesta.